I need Create a user in google with script
Getting the Un-Authorized error while hitting the "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users" API with deluge script
{"responseText":{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Not Authorized to access this resource/api","errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized to access this resource/api","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}]}},"responseHeader":{"date":"Mon, 12 Aug 2024 14:10:48 GMT","server":"ESF","content-length":"260","x-xss-protection":"0","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","vary":"Referer","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000"},"responseCode":403}

Need to add a user in google workspace , as i am able to archive this operation in azure.

Please edit your question to be a question - "I need" is not a question, and neither is an error message :). Please see [mre] for some guidance.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Permission required to add user
Given that our knowledge is only limited to the question you have provided, It looks like you're receiving a “403 Forbidden” error when trying to access the Google Admin Console API to create a new user. This error typically occurs because you don't have the necessary permissions to perform the action. Specifically, it means that you are not a super administrator for the domain you're trying to manage. To resolve this issue, you'll need to ensure you have the appropriate super admin rights.
Here is the sample code below which shows how to add a new user using Google Admin console API in app script.
function addUser() {
  let user = {
    // TODO (developer) - Replace primaryEmail value with yours
    primaryEmail: 'sample@example.com',
    name: {
      givenName: 'Sample',
      familyName: 'Sample'
    },
    // Generate a random password string.
    password: Math.random().toString(36)
  };
  try {
    user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
    console.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer)- Handle exception from the API
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

IMPORTANT NOTE: You must add the Admin SDK API in the services of your App script. see this  for your reference.
This is the output of the code. 
Please visit this public documentation for your reference of the code.
Add user using Admin SDK Directory
